# PHP 5 functioning returning an array- interaction without assignment?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, php-5.3

I'm wondering if this kind of thing will ever be possible in PHP (and whether it already is and I'm just missing something...)

```
<?php

function test() {
 return array(
  'id'=>10,
  'name'=>'John'
 );
}

echo 'Your name is: '.test()['name'];

?>
```

I'd really like to be able to use returned arrays directly instead of first assigning them to a var... possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: **don't think so**

The PHP lexer doesn't recognize these kind of statements so a change would require some major changes within the core components of PHP. Although I must admit, that I don't see any reason why the lexer has been written that way.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do in this way, but with php5 and OOP you have some alternatives...